# Javascript fetch handle both json and blob

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, es6-promise, asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api

Using javascript fetch and invoking a rest service that returns a blob if successful, otherwise returns an error message as json.  How would this be handled in the fetch?  The actual service is a asp.net web api implementation that returns a FileStreamResult (or FileContentResult) when successful, otherwise returns an error code with json containing the error message.  Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    return response.blob();
  } else {
    return response.json();
}

}).then(function(myBlob) {  // here I would also like to function(jsonError)
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob); 
  myImage.src = objectURL; 
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you want to go down two fairly different paths, this is one of the relatively-rare situations where you probably want to nest handlers:

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
            var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
            myImage.src = objectURL;
        });
    } else {
        return response.json().then(function(jsonError) {
            // ...
        });
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested then block to pass literally whatever you want to your next then handler. Sample:

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.blob()
            .then(function (myBlob) {
                return {
                    blob: myBlob
                };
            });
    } else {
        return response.json()
            .then(function (myJson) {
                return {
                    json: myJson
                };
            });
    }

}).then(function (myData) { 
    if(myData.blob){
        // Handle blob case
    }else{
        // Handle JSON case
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
});
```

Perhaps a more semantically accurate way of handling this is rejecting when there is an error.

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.blob();
    } else {
        return response.json()
            .then(function (myJson) {
                return Promise.reject(myJson);
            });
    }

}).then(function (myData) {
    // Handle blob case
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Handle JSON case
});
```

Comment: There's no point to `return Promise.resolve(value);` from within a `then` handler, just use `return value;`. `then` always returns a promise, which is resolved with the value you return (or rejected with what you throw) if you don't return a promise. (If you do, the promise `then` creates and returns chains to it.) So it just creates an extra layer. :-)

Comment: Ah yes. That's a bad habit I have for the purpose of 'readability'. Need to stop doing that :)